# Jenkins Jobs with all the drop down values of Extended Choice Param

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I have used Extended Choice Parameter plug in in Jenkins to list the possible matching of files(Around 30 ****.xml files). This works pretty fine, just needed to select once value of the parameter from the drop down after clicking on Build now link. Now I wanted to kick off the build automatically with all the possible values of that drop down. Wondering, if it's possible?

Comment: Have you tried changing the parameter type to multi-select?

Comment: I checked with multi select; with this I can select more than one. But I am thinking about executing the build with all the values one after another automatically if it's possible.

Comment: Have another job read the directory and call your current job once for each file and passing in one of the files.

Comment: @PeterSchuetze : Thank you for your response. I guess, what you are saying, could do it, but might get bit complicated. I was after some kind of simple solution. At the end, I wanted to get rid off the problem of executing soap ui multiple projects execution using maven and jenkins. At present, I am reading all the project xmls files through shell script and amending the pom during runtime and executing all the project from one job. Having a solution through maven/jenkins could have been very handy. Like, with surefire plugin we can execute tests that match some user defined criteria.